# Saving the state of a button onSaveInstanceState

Tags: android, button

Ok, this one is really tricky to me. The idea of this is a time log for EMS. You press a button by the action taken, and it logs the time for later use. I managed to figure out how to save the TextView into a string. Now, how on earth do I save the logTime1.setEnabled(false); so that on rotation or on leaving the activity, it restores it disabled? Eventually I will have another button beside it that will allow you to edit which will unlock the button. Here is the code.

public class TimeLog extends Activity{

```
boolean logTimeDis1=true;
Button logTime1;
String time1;
TextView ivTimeStamp;
int counter=0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.time_log);
    logTime1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logTime1);
    ivTimeStamp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ivTimeStamp);
    if(savedInstanceState != null) logTime1.setEnabled(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("logTimeDis1", true));
    logTime1.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {


        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            time1 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.US).format(new Date());

            ivTimeStamp.setText(time1);
            logTime1.setEnabled(false);
            logTimeDis1 = false;
            return false;
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    counter++;
}


@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putString("ivTimeStamp", ivTimeStamp.getText().toString());
    outState.putBoolean("logTimeDis1", logTimeDis1);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    ivTimeStamp.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("ivTimeStamp"));
}




}
```

Comment: You need to store a boolean in your bundle that determines if it is set or not and then in onCreate, if(savedInstanceState != null) logTime.setEnabled(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("some_key", true);

Comment: You are such a big help man. All this trial and error is really teaching me how all of this stuff works. It's a great way to really learn some intermediate stuff.

Comment: The joys of programming :)

Comment: Ok I got it where if it is pressed, it will save it. However, if it is not pressed, and say you move to horizontal view and it restarts, it automatically locks it without being pressed. I must be doing something wrong here.

Comment: Mind updating your code? Probably a simple mistake.

Comment: Sorry if it is sloppy. I clean up as I go and simplify things when I figure out, you know, how to simplify them...haha.

Comment: There are 2 things you can do, you can set logTimeDis1 to true when you declare it initially (instead of just leaving it open). You can also change the initial boolean set to `logTime1.setEnabled(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("logTmeDis1", true));` which will set the default value to true (clickable) as opposed to false (unclickable)

Answer (score 0):

So, in this line

```
if(savedInstanceState != null) logTime1.setEnabled(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("logTmeDis1", false));
```

you don't check if savedInstanceState contains logTmeDis1. Say, savedInstanceState is not null, but does not have logTmeDis1, you'll get false and your button locked. Actually, you don't have to check it in this case, just change false to true, and it should work correctly.

Comment: So remove if(savedInstanceState != null)? Tired that and got a nullpointerexception. I also tried changing it to true, still does a similar thing. I think it may be a problem with my onSaveInstanceState not saving the value of logTimeDis1.

Comment: And by 'similar thing' I mean it just allows the the button to become reEnabled upon screen rotation with the button being pressed prior.

Comment: My suggestion was to leave everything like it was but to change "false" to "true". Isn't it working?

Comment: Ok, say I press the button to lock in the current time. Upon rotation or moving to another screen and coming back, it's still locked. Working as intended. Now let's say I hit back go go back to this activity, ok so everything is reset because it called onDestroy, right? So WITHOUT pressing the button to lock in the time, it stays open. And WITHOUT pressing the button and rotating the screen or going to another screen, it locks without being pressed. This is after I changed the value to true.

Comment: Sorry, are we talking about changing:
`if(savedInstanceState != null) logTime1.setEnabled(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("logTmeDis1", false));`
to:
`if(savedInstanceState != null) logTime1.setEnabled(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("logTmeDis1", true));`
In this case it's kind of strange that it doesn't work since it's the only line that can change the button state and it's always true in the absence of previously saved logTmeDis1, which is the case. Did you try to watch logTmeDis1 in debug?

Comment: if(savedInstanceState != null) logTime1.setEnabled(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("logTmeDis1", true)); is what it is now, yes.

Comment: Ok now it's getting annoying. I changed the default value of logTimeDis1 to true. Now it seems to work as intended. If I rotate the screen, it still stays locked. But if I rotate it back it goes back to being unlocked again. Updating code.

Comment: hey @jham, not sure if you have already solved the problem but I've finally got time to think about it.  
The missing part was:
    `if (savedInstanceState != null) {
   logTimeDis1 = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("logTimeDis1", true);
   logTime1.setEnabled(logTimeDis1);
  }`  
We just forgot to save logTimeDis1 value when recreating activity so it was always true on recreation.